# Laravel 4 Query

Tags: php, mysql, api, laravel-4

I'm creating a nearby android application, using laravel 4.1 as my API.

I found this useful tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
but I can't seem to rewrite the query to work with laravel 4.

How can I use this query in Eloquent

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Thank you.

Comment: To be explicit: you want this to work with `Eloquent`? Because the raw query can just be done as-is of course.

Comment: @Wrikken yes I would like this done through Eloquent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's Query Builder is just for easier and faster programming and if you already have your query, you can use it directly.

```
$stmt = DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare("SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
");
$stmt->execute();
```

Edit

...and Eloquent is extended from query builder so you can use all query builder methods with your Eloquent model.